# Thermometer to USB

Tags: usb

I am fairly new to electronics and I'd like to connect a thermometer (DS18S20) which generates 9-bit output. I'd like to connect this to my computer through USB and read the data it provides programmatically. Programming is not a problem.

The problem is: how can I connect this to an USB port so my software can read the raw bits?

---

Simply connecting it to a pin is not the good way I guess…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://www.leonheller.com/usb/) are the details of a simple USB interface I designed around a PIC18F2455, using some software provided by Brad Minch. You could mount the DS18S20 on the PCB prototyping area, interface it to the 18F2455, and modify the software to transmit the temperature to your PC via the USB port. The PCB is available from Olimex.

Comment: Little question: the device driver is for Windows it says. I don't have a Windows machine ^^. Are there also drivers available for Linux or Mac OS X?

Comment: @Radek S It looks as if the software needs to be compiled using MinGW. If that's the case, then it could probably be easily ported to GNU/Linux or MacOS X.

Comment: That should work for Linux, at any rate.

Answer (score 2):

You can't connect a DS18S20 directly to a USB port, because they both different protocols. You need something in the middle to translate, like a microcontroller.

I've done something very similar except I used the RS232 com port on the computer as that allows you to use a much wider range of microcontrollers. Of course thus also required a line driver as well.

If you want to do this, then you should start by reading the DS18S20 datasheet. It has all the commands you need to get it to take a temperature reading, and send it over its data wire. You'll also need a microcontroller, and write the firmware to talk to the sensor and get back data readings, and send them to the computer.

Comment: Is there any reason why we couldn't just connect DS18S20's data pin to a MAX232 or similar and have the computer do all the decoding? Couple of transistors could be used to switch the data pin between RX and TX pins of the port and other two pins could be used to control transistors. After that one of the USB to serial chips could be used or a prefabricated USB based serial port.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: possibly yes, that's a good idea, it it can be done quick enough to talk to the DS18S20. I think you need at least 15us. You should add this as your own answer!

Comment: @Andrejako, @BG100, one of you make a schematic and add it in. show using RTS or the like to switch the transistors and an FT232 chip to do it. The user is not in heavy electronics so a "how you do it" schematic could be in order here.

Comment: @Kortuk♦ Since I was considering making a thermometer connected to serial port one of these days, I'll probably make a schematic soon.

Comment: @AndrejaKo, Sounds great, make an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to have a look at [this website](http://www.waitingforfriday.com/index.php/Building_a_PIC18F_USB_device), which has a fairly recent proposition on how to make a low-cost usb interface, based on a pic. The code explains in full open source how to have bidirectionnal communication (blink a led from PC / respond to a button press), with both device and PC code.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to connect DS18S20 temperature sensor to PC via USB as explained [here](http://www.obdev.at/products/vusb/prjdetail.php?pid=71).

Comment: If that link dies your answer will become completely useless. We need details and we need them here.

Comment: Without any votes my answer already seams useless, so I will not bother in this case. Thank you for your remark.